# Pnp "cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations" on nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, nestjs, yarnpkg

I'd like to ask a question because I don't know what to do. I'm working on a nestjs project and using its capabilities to generate applications in a single repository. As a result, the file structure of my project looks like this:

```bash
|-- ROOT_DIR
|-- .yarn
|-- Apps #directory for my apps 
|-- Libs #directory for additional libs (prisma, logger, etc.)
|-- package.json
|-- ...other files
```

> .yarnrc.yml

```yaml
nodeLinker: pnp
yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.2.2.cjs
```

> package.json

```json
{
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "copy:prisma": "cp -R",
    "format": "prettier --write \"apps/**/*.ts\" \"libs/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/apps/wallet/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./apps/wallet/test/jest-e2e.json",
    "update:sdk": "yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks",
    "prisma:migrate": "yarn prisma migrate dev --name ",
    "prisma:gen": "yarn pnpify prisma generate && yarn copy:prisma",
    "prisma:deploy": "yarn prisma migrate deploy"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "^2.0.2",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-fastify": "^8.4.5",
    "@nestjs/schedule": "^2.0.1",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^5.2.1",
    "@prisma/client": "4.15.0",
    "@yarnpkg/pnpify": "^4.0.0-rc.6",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "cache-manager": "^4.0.1",
    "cache-manager-redis-store": "^2.0.0",
    "casper-js-sdk": "^2.9.1",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "fastify": "^3.29.0",
    "fastify-swagger": "^5.2.0",
    "near-api-js": "^1.1.0",
    "nest-winston": "^1.6.2",
    "nestjs-http-promise": "^1.2.3",
    "puppeteer": "^21.4.1",
    "redis": "3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "winston": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/bn.js": "^5.1.1",
    "@types/cache-manager": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/cron": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "27.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "28.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "prisma": "4.15.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "28.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": ".",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/apps/",
      "<rootDir>/libs/"
    ],
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.2.2",
}
```

It so happens that I need to use the name pnp, but when installing dependencies I get errors on all the libraries: Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations, which gives me the impression that the indexing was a failure. Tell me how to fix it, or which way to look

Comment: btw this has nothing to do with nestjs, it's just typescript compiler stuff. Thus, add your tsconfig files in the question as well